# What is the default culture for C# 6 string interpolation?

Tags: c#, string-interpolation, c#-6.0

In C# 6 what is the default culture for the new string interpolation?

I've seen conflicting reports of both Invariant and Current Culture.

I would like a definitive answer and I'm keeping my fingers crossed for Invariant.

Comment: I downvoted because this question shows no research effort.

Comment: I did a lot of searching before posting this question, I had found some sources including stackoverflow that said Invariant.  I had found other sources including stackoverflow that said current culture.  This is why I asked the question.  Thanks.

Comment: @AaronStainback actually there are a lot of question in SO from people that found they couldn't use InvariantCulture with interpolation. Feel free to downvote whoever says it uses the InvariantCulture. In any case, just changing Thread.CurrentCulture in a unit test would show this

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Using string interpolation in C# is compiled into a simple call to  `String.Format`. You can see with [TryRolsyn](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoADsAIwBswBjGUogQxBBgGEYBvbGNmfYsmANwHswAExgBZABQBKVuxbs5MFACdIsCFXSoYAXhgAiAlUW6c89kpUxFqEMCLJtMACS6majQF9j0tu+zugA==) that this:

```
public void M()
{
    string name = "bar";
    string result = $"{name}";
}
```

Is compiled into this:

```
public void M()
{
    string arg = "bar";
    string text = string.Format("{0}", arg);
}
```

It's clear that this doesn't use an overload that accepts a format provider, [hence it uses the current culture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx#FTaskList).

You can however compile the interpolation into `FormattbleString` instead which keeps the format and arguments separate and pass a specific culture when generating the final string:

```
FormattableString formattableString = $"{name}";
string result = formattableString.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Now since (as you prefer) it's very common to use `InvariantCulture` specifically there's a shorthand for that:

```
string result = FormattableString.Invariant($"{name}");
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that the [`FormattableString.Invariant`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formattablestring.invariant(v=vs.110).aspx) method is only available from .Net Framework 4.6 onwards.

Comment: To save on typing, you can use C# 6.0's `using static System.FormattableString;` so you only need to type `String result = Invariant($"foo {bar} baz");`.

Comment: *hence it uses the current culture.*. Such an annoying decision by MS. For every hardcoded string in codebase now I need extra machinery to make it invariant. I mean what other strings would one hardcode? For culture specific strings we anyway have to use resource files.

Comment: @nawfal Then you can just set your app's culture to invariant and make sure to use culture specically everywhere it matters.

Comment: @i3arnon how do I do that and also get current user's culture? I of course do not know what culture my user is gonna be.