# C# 6 how to format double using interpolated string?

Tags: c#, double, string-interpolation, c#-6.0

I have used interpolated strings for messages containing `string` variables like `$"{EmployeeName}, {Department}"`. Now I want to use an interpolated string for showing a formatted `double`.

Example

```
var aNumberAsString = aDoubleValue.ToString("0.####");
```

How can I write it as an interpolated string? Something like `$"{aDoubleValue} ...."`

Comment: Note: string interpolation uses current culture. For insensitive interpolation, you can use Invariant from System.FormattableString: `Invariant($"at {num}")`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203261/what-is-the-default-culture-for-c-sharp-6-string-interpolation

Answer (score 187, accepted):

You can specify a format string after an expression with a colon (`:`):

```
var aNumberAsString = $"{aDoubleValue:0.####}";
```

Comment: The list of possible formatting specifications can be found [here (for custom formats)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings) and [here (for standard formats)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)

Comment: Does not work on my German Windows PC with VS 2022: the double values use comma as decimal separator (instead of a dot).

Answer (score 27):

A colon after the variable specifies a format,

```
Console.Write($"{aDoubleValue:0.####}");
```

Answer (score 7):

Or like this:

```cs
Console.Write($"{aDoubleValue:f4}");
```