# What does the ":0" formatting mean in this interpolated string?

Tags: c#

I've come across this interpolated string in a Unity sample: `$"Starting in: {time:0}"`

Apparently the `:0` format rounds `time` (a float) to the nearest integer, but there's no further explanation than that. When I tried replacing the 0 with different numbers, I got outputs that just seemed random.

What is this format actually doing? What's the significance of the 0? And is there a name for this formatting?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation#how-to-specify-a-format-string-for-an-interpolation-expression

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37113595/c-sharp-6-how-to-format-double-using-interpolated-string

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings

Comment: @gunr2171 thanks! It's always hard to find documentation for something when you don't know what it's called!

Comment: @LongRamen: but the internet has search tools. When I tried to imagine the most basic search terms for your problem, I came up with `"c# format number strings"`. The first two (non Stackoverflow) links were to the .NET dics on Standard and Custom formatting of numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @gunr2171 commented, this is an example of the "zero placeholder" format string: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings