# What does the dollar sign and { } mean as a locator selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Hi I don't understand the locator with the $ sign and the name in braces {name}.  Am I right in thinking, using this way you can use the locator as an IList and also a non IList.  Here is the locator:

`public IList<IWebElement> ResultByName(string name) => dr.FindElements(By.Id($"//div[text() = '{name}']"));`

And then its used in the code snippet:

```
IList<IWebElement> list = _regRep.ResultByName(emailID);
int actualCount = list.Count;
Assert.AreEqual(1, list.Count, "Only one user should match email " + emailID);
```

There is a flaw in this because even though there is an `emailID` in the table it still gives a count of 0 which is not what is expected?

Comment: This is a C# feature called [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated). The dollar sign is not part of the string itself, nor is it anything specific to selectors.

Comment: `By.Id($"//span[text()[contains(.,'{name}')]]")` I am going to guess that is a bug, since that does _not_ look like an ID.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the default culture for C# 6 string interpolation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203261/what-is-the-default-culture-for-c-sharp-6-string-interpolation)

Comment: Why doesn't the list.count equal 1 as its clearly visible in the table?

Comment: I went with this locator instead and it works now `public IList<IWebElement> ResultByName(string name) => dr.FindElements(By.XPath("(//div[@class='vt-list-view-cell vt-list-view-cell__body vt-list-view-cell--overflow'])[3][text()='"+name+"']"));`

Answer (score 1):

This is an [interpolated string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation) that allows you to add expressions into your string:

```
var myValue = "interpolate";
var interpolatedText = $"The dollar sign allows you to {myValue} text and literal C# expressions.";
```

It was introduced with C# 6.0 and allows you to avoid using `String.Format`.