# C# Currency Formatting

Tags: c#, formatting, currency

Is there any way to format a number in the currency format (in the current Culture) using a custom format string?

For example:

```
1525.00 -> $1,525 (no trailing zeros)
1525.25 -> $1,525.25 (show decimals only when necessary)
```

We have tried different formats but none of them can produce the above.

Comment: Have you checked out the [documentation on numeric formatting of strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#currency-format-specifier-c)?

Comment: What is the expected result for 1525.351? 1525.3?

Comment: What is the data type of the number (decimal? double?)?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, no, you *can't* do that with a "one" format since you don't want show decimal parts for the first one but you "want" to show decimals part for the second one. I don't think there will be a "simple" format for both.

You can check the [`Currency format specifier (C)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#currency-format-specifier-c) for that as;

```
var v = 1525.00;
$"{v:C0}".Dump();
```

returns `$1,525` and

```
var v = 1525.25;
$"{v:C2}".Dump();
```

return `$1,525.25`.

Just a note, [string interpolation uses `CurrentCulture`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33221629/447156) settings and in that case, I assume your current culture is somewhat based on *english-based* or [`InvariantCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture?view=net-5.0) for generate `CurrencySymbol`, `NumberGroupSeparator` and `NumberDecimalSeparator` as `$`, `,` and `.` respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Does this count?

```
static string MyCustomCurrencyString(decimal d) => d % 1 == 0 ? $"{d:C0}" : $"{d:C2}";
```

Let's test it:

```
Console.WriteLine(ZerosAreBad(1525));
Console.WriteLine(ZerosAreBad(1525.25m));
```

It works!

```
$1,525
$1,525.25
```